# Who creates the JSESSIONID cookie in Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, session, cookies, spring-security

In my web application theres the requirement that each locale (accessible under the paths `/de_DE/`, `/en_US/` etc.) respectively has it's own session. I did this by overwriting the session `CookieGenerator` so that it sets a path for the session cookies, so the browser sends the right session id for the accessed locale.

The problem I have now is that Spring Security changes the session ID after the login and generates a new session cookie somewhere. This cookie doesn't have the path I want it to. Where can I manipulate how Spring generates the session cookie?

Answer (score 1):

Look at `SessionManagementFilter` as here all session related activities happens with the help of `SessionAuthenticationStretegy` classes.